# Model with time as predictor but some rows have large time span

Tags: regression, time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I want to model a linguistic feature (number of a certain word at the beginning of the sentence) through centuries. I am familiar with logistic regressions, Poisson regressions and GAMM to model such things through time but this time some rows have large intervals instead of a precise year, so my dataset looks like this

| Text | Period | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1325 | 26 |
| B | 1300-1500 | 24 |
| C | 1410 | 36 |
| D | 1712 | 22 |

Is there any way I can include the interval of text B in the model together with other rows which have a more precise year specification?